# Split a PdfTable in next page

Tags: java, pdf, itext

How to split a `PdfTable` in next page in Java?

I am generating a **pdf** document using **itext** in java. The pdf has a header and a table. When the table continues to the next page, two rows of the table overlaps into the header. How to display the remaining table rows below the header in the next page. Here I am using **Header_Footer java class** and call the object of the Header_Footer in the **jsp** page like-

```
Header_Footer event = new Header_Footer();
writer.setPageEvent(event);
```

My Header_Footer class is give below

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mis4acjml;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.ExceptionConverter;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
/**
 *
 * @author kanika
 */
public class Header_Footer extends PdfPageEventHelper{
    String header;
    PdfTemplate total;
    /**
         * Allows us to change the content of the header.
         * @param header The new header String
         */
    public Header_Footer()
    {
        header="The Assam Co-operative Jute Mills Ltd.";
    }
    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    /**
         * Creates the PdfTemplate that will hold the total number of pages.
         * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onOpenDocument(
         *      com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document)
         */
    public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        total = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(30, 16);
    }

    /**
         * Adds a header to every page
         * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onEndPage(
         *      com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document)
         */
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        try {
            table.setWidths(new int[]{24, 24, 2});
            table.setTotalWidth(527);
            table.setLockedWidth(true);
            table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(20);
            table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
            table.addCell(header);

            table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            table.addCell(String.format("Page %d of", writer.getPageNumber()));
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(Image.getInstance(total));
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
            table.addCell(cell); 
            table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 803, writer.getDirectContent());
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fills out the total number of pages before the document is closed.
     *
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onCloseDocument(
     * com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document)
     */
    public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(total, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,new Phrase(String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber() - 1)),2, 2, 0);
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem needs to be solved in code you're not showing. You're adding the header at position x = 34, y = 803. I assume you're creating the `Document` object like this:

```
Document document = new Document();
```

This means you're creating a document with A4 pages and margins of 36 user units (half an inch).

A4 means that the height of the document will be 842. If we substract the margin, we have y = 806 as top margin. As you're adding something at position 803, you need a larger top margin. See the [constructor of the Document class](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html#Document%28com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) for more info.

For instance:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 72, 36);
```